# Convert char[] to byte[] results in higher count

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, type-conversion, arrays

Im trying to cast a char-array into a byte-array.

```
char[] cc = new char[] { ((char)(byte)210) }; // Count = 1
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cc); // Count = 2
```

The conversion results in 2 entries for my byte-array `{195, 146}`.
I guess theres a problem with the encoding. Any help is appreciated.

---

*After facing some problems I've written this 2 lines for the purpose of testing, so dont mind the style.*

Thanks

Comment: It is not a problem. It is how UTF8 encode characters with code point equal or above U+0080.

Comment: you just want to cast? `cc.Cast<byte>().ToArray();` or `cc.Select(c=>(byte)c).ToArray();`

Comment: I'm not certain that I understand your issue.  Almost nobody is using ASCII since, oh, like 1980.  In Unicode, which Java encodes as UTF16, there is more than one byte per character.

Comment: @PetSerAl Maybe not a problem in general, but a problem for as Im expecting another result. Im still looking forward getting on the point "why".

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary First one gave me an exception. The second one truly works. What about going for the answer?

Comment: @C4ud3x You does not say anything about result, you are expecting. UTF8 able to represent more than 256 different characters, so of course, some of characters have to use more than one byte to be encoded.

Comment: no. i prefer not because this was mainly about why you get two length byte array from enconding. hope professionals will give a right answer plus right way @C4ud3x

Comment: What is your actual purpose here? What are the bytes going to be used to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As M.kazemAkhgary said in the comments above:

```
cc.Select(c=>(byte)c).ToArray();
```

The clue was to cast instead of using converting. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 can use more than just one byte to store a character. It uses only one byte for the ASCII characters within the range from 0-127, other characters need two or more bytes to be stored.

You are encoding the ASCII character `210` which is from the extended ASCII character (numeric value > 127), UTF-8 uses two bytes to store this character.

Comment: That at least makes sense to me. But I cant convert my byte-array back this way. Im getting a very different result. Is there any way to stay on single-byte entries?

Comment: M.kazemAkhgary got it in the upper comments.

Comment: Use a single-byte encoding, or stick with those characters that have a single-byte representation for the characters you use. Of course that won't handle all characters, but it can't as a single byte can only cover 256 values, rather than the 1114112 values you need to cover all valid character codes or even just the hundreds of thousands that are in use.

Comment: Can't you just convert the UTF8 back to ASCII using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`?